# Python change dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary

I have below dictionary

```
{
  "Brand_Name" : ["Samsung","Apple","Huawei","Nokia"], 
  "Link" : ["samsung-phones-9.php","apple-phones-48.php","huawei-phones-58.php","nokia-phones-1.php"]
}
```

I want it to convert to this

```
{
    "Brand_Name" : "Samsung",
    "Link" : "samsung-phones-9.php"
},
{
    "Brand_Name" : "Apple",
    "Link" : "apple-phones-48.php"
},
{
    "Brand_Name" : "Huawei",
    "Link" : "huawei-phones-58.php"
},
{
    "Brand_Name" : "Nokia",
    "Link" : "nokia-phones-1.php"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `zip` with `list` comprehension,

```
>>> x = 'Brand_Name': ['Samsung', 'Apple', 'Huawei', 'Nokia'], 'Link': ['samsung-phones-9.php', 'apple-phones-48.php', 'huawei-phones-58.php', 'nokia-phones-1.php']}
>>> [{'Brand_Name': brand, 'Link': link} for brand,link in zip(x['Brand_Name'], x['Link'])]
[{'Brand_Name': 'Samsung', 'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Apple', 'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Huawei', 'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Nokia', 'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
d = {"Brand_Name" : ["Samsung","Apple","Huawei","Nokia"], 
     "Link" : ["samsung-phones-9.php","apple-phones-48.php","huawei-phones-58.php","nokia-phones-1.php"]}
k = list(d.keys())

[{k[0]: v1, k[1]: v2} for v1, v2 in zip(d[k[0]], d[k[1]])]
```

Output:

```
[{'Brand_Name': 'Samsung', 'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php'},
 {'Brand_Name': 'Apple', 'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php'},
 {'Brand_Name': 'Huawei', 'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php'},
 {'Brand_Name': 'Nokia', 'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php'}]
```

The orderedness of `dict` will **not** matter, as keys are always linked with its value(s). Simple test shows:

```
# test_dict.py
d = {"Brand_Name" : ["Samsung","Apple","Huawei","Nokia"],
     "Link" : ["samsung-phones-9.php","apple-phones-48.php","huawei-phones-58.php","nokia-phones-1.php"]}
k = list(d.keys())

print([{k[0]: v1, k[1]: v2} for v1, v2 in zip(d[k[0]], d[k[1]])])
```

Test it multiple times (tested using default python3 of ubuntu 16.04, i.e. `3.5.2`):

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do python3 test_dict.py; done
[{'Brand_Name': 'Samsung', 'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Apple', 'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Huawei', 'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Nokia', 'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php'}]
[{'Brand_Name': 'Samsung', 'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Apple', 'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Huawei', 'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Nokia', 'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php'}]
[{'Brand_Name': 'Samsung', 'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Apple', 'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Huawei', 'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Nokia', 'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php'}]
[{'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Samsung'}, {'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Apple'}, {'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Huawei'}, {'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Nokia'}]
[{'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Samsung'}, {'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Apple'}, {'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Huawei'}, {'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Nokia'}]
[{'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Samsung'}, {'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Apple'}, {'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Huawei'}, {'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Nokia'}]
[{'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Samsung'}, {'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Apple'}, {'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Huawei'}, {'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Nokia'}]
[{'Brand_Name': 'Samsung', 'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Apple', 'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Huawei', 'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php'}, {'Brand_Name': 'Nokia', 'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php'}]
[{'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Samsung'}, {'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Apple'}, {'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Huawei'}, {'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Nokia'}]
[{'Link': 'samsung-phones-9.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Samsung'}, {'Link': 'apple-phones-48.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Apple'}, {'Link': 'huawei-phones-58.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Huawei'}, {'Link': 'nokia-phones-1.php', 'Brand_Name': 'Nokia'}]
```

Only the order of *appearance* is changed, but not the links.

Comment: Upvoted for the extra mile :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, so you've got two lists and you want to merge them pair-wise? In that case, `zip` does exactly what you want:

```
d1 = {
    "Brand_Name" : ["Samsung","Apple","Huawei","Nokia"]
    "Link" : ["samsung-phones-9.php","apple-phones-48.php","huawei-phones-58.php","nokia-phones-1.php"]
}

pairs = zip(d1["Brand_Name"], d1["Link"])
d2 = dict(pairs)
print(d2)
```